# zend framework website not running by localhost, how to configure it in htdocs in xampp server

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, fatal-error

when I try to run my website I get error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception: Invalid controller specified (error) in
C:\xampp\htdocs\dms\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:248 Stack trace: #0
C:\xampp\htdocs\dms\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1
C:\xampp\htdocs\dms\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2
C:\xampp\htdocs\dms\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() #3
C:\xampp\htdocs\dms\index.php(93): Zend_Application->run() #4 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\dms\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php on line 248
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc

https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html

> By default, Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler will forward to ErrorController::errorAction() in the default module. You may set alternate values for these by using the various accessors available to the plugin:

So it is possible that your application generates an error and then try to dispatch the error controller but it is not present. Check if you have the ErrorController in your application.

Comment: I am not getting name of file is contained error handling.

Comment: Please check in you application if you have the "application/controllers/ErrorController.php" file, do you have it?